# javascript wrap text with tag

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am adding a button to tinyMCE and I want to know how to wrap text inside tags with javascript, for instance (this highlighted text gets wrapped inside `[highlight][/highlight]` tags).
and now the entire tinymce

```
(function() {
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.shoutButton', {
    init : function(ed, url) {
        ed.addButton('shout.button', {
            title : 'shout.button',
            image : 'viral.gif',
            onclick : function() {
                window.alert("booh");
        });
    },
    createControl : function(n, cm) {
        return null;
    },
    getInfo : function() {
        return {
            longname : "Shout button",
            author : 'SAFAD',
            authorurl : 'http://safadsoft.com/',
            infourl : 'http://safadsoft.com/',
            version : "1.0"
        };
    }
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add('shout.button', tinymce.plugins.ShoutButton);
```

})();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was syntax errors, not properly closed brackets and some missing semi-colons, using the help of the awesome [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)'s JSHint and JSLint I fixed it :

```
(function () {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.shoutButton', {
        init: function (ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('shout.button', {
                title: 'shout.button',
                image: 'viral.gif',
                onclick: function () {
                    window.alert("booh");
                }
            });
            createControl: function (n, cm) {
                return null;
            }
            getInfo: function () {
                return {
                    longname: "Shout button",
                    author: 'You !',
                    authorurl: 'http://example.com/',
                    infourl: 'http://example.com/',
                    version: "1.0"
                };
            }
        }
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('shout.button', tinymce.plugins.ShoutButton);
})();
```

Best Regards

Comment: I down voted your answer because you didn't post the actual final code that achieves the goal.

Comment: Agreed,for that and I have edited the answer, accept my sincere apologies !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the setSelectionRange (mozilla/webkit) or selection.createRange (IE) methods to find the currently highlighted text inside a textarea.
I put up an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/2YNpJ/), but have commented out your regexp since it hangs the browser in many instances. You need to make it more restrictive, and it currently passes a lot of other things than youtube url's as well.

However, the example has a working solution how to get the currently selected text, which you can, after fixing your pattern, apply to the idPattern.exec().

```
idPattern = /(?:(?:[^v]+)+v.)?([^&=]{11})(?=&|$)/;
  //  var vidId = prompt("YouTube Video", "Enter the id or url for your video");


    var vidId;
      el = document.getElementById('texty');
      if (el.setSelectionRange) {
        var vidId = el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);
      }
      else if(document.selection.createRange()) {
          var vidId = document.selection.createRange().text; 
      }

   alert(vidId);
```

EDIT: Wrapping the highlighted text and outputting it back to the element. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2YNpJ/51/)

```
el = document.getElementById('texty');
  if (el.setSelectionRange) {

     el.value = el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart) + "[highlight]" + el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd) + "[/highlight]" + el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);

  }
  else if(document.selection.createRange()) {
      document.selection.createRange().text = "[highlight]" + document.selection.createRange().text + "[/highlight]"; 
  }
```

Comment: i said that was an example in some tutorial i found for making a button to tinyMCE, all i want is to wrap the text with highlight tag

Comment: Well that's exactly what it does. It finds the highlighted text for you to use for whatever you need it to do.

Comment: now after it finds it, how to wrap it under those the [highlight][/highlight] tags, i am bad @ JS

Comment: I added an example how you can use it to wrap it in those tags.

Comment: the entire TinyMCE editor disappears when i add my plugin, edited the post containing the code

Comment: Your edited question has now nothing to do with the original question, nor is it related to how to grab the currently selected text with javascript.