# How do I use Javascript or jQuery get highlighted text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get javascript or jquery to grab me text that I've selected/high lighted with my mouse or keyboard?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

Comment: this is a nice plugin for selecting text and manipulating, should be useful: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/a-tools

Comment: @XGreen: That's for text inputs and textareas, not the regular page selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the above, this outputs the selected text to a div (adapted from http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language=javascript>
$(document).ready( function() {
var txt = '';
function getSelected()
{   
  if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
  }
  else if(document.getSelection) {
    txt = document.getSelection();
  }
  else if(document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
      txt = txt.toString();
  return txt;  
}

$('#container').mouseup( function() {
    $('#message').html(getSelected());
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#message {
    min-height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="container">
<p>Text to select</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you're supporting Safari 2 and earlier, you don't need both `window.getSelection()` and `document.getSelection()`.

Answer (score 0):

For textareas, you can use this (as seen on [javascript wrap text with tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164093/javascript-wrap-text-with-tag/6164403#6164403) ):

```
 var val;
          el = document.getElementById('textarea');
          if (el.setSelectionRange) {
    //webkit & ff
            var val = el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);
          }
          else if(document.selection.createRange()) {
// ie
              var val = document.selection.createRange().text; 
          }
```